# Regex for Name validation with atleast one alpahbet(A-z)

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex that should validate it should contain atleast one alphabet(A-Z,a-z) and optionally numbers(0-9).

Valid names:

- aaaa
- aaaa1
- SO
- John P. Example

Invalid names,

- 1111
- @@@@

the Regex I have tried so far

```
[a-zA-Z0-9\.\'\-_\s]{1,20}
```

and

```
function validateFirstName(a) {
  if (/[0-9]/.test(a) && /[a-zA-Z]/.test(a)) {
      return false;
  } else {
      return true;
  }
}
```

but both doesn't work.

Can anyone help in this regard?

Comment: "Doesn't work" means what exactly? It matches not everything it should match? It matches even what it should not match? You get a syntax error? You get a runtime error?

Comment: Well, `/[0-9]/.test('aaaa')` obviously results in false.

Comment: Please don't consider that you can validate firstname like this. Names are a really complicated a weird world, your requirement would simply cut millions of people from entering their own name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

To explain:

- The bit in the middle square brackets (the "meat in the sandwich") matches an alphabet character. The + after it makes sure there is at least one of these.
- The other two square-bracketed expressions (the "bread in the sandwich") match alphanumeric characters. The * after each allow any number of these.
- The ^ and $ surrounding the whole thing make sure it is the whole text being looked at and not just part of it.

Comment: but what about spaces in the name?

Comment: The OP's function is called `validateFirstName`. This makes me think it would assume it would only be applied the first name (e.g. John in the "John P. Example").

Answer (score 1):

`[a-zA-Z]+.*|.*[a-zA-Z]+|.*[a-zA-Z]+.*` match the examples you supplied.

Answer (score 1):

So you want any number of a-z char or number, then at least one a-z char and any number of a-z char or number again:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

This should work fine.

Comment: You said that 1111 is invalid and it doesn't match for it. For aaaa it's matching for me. What do you use to evaluate the pattern? (regexpal.com and GNU grep seems to like it)

Answer (score 1):

If you only want t check whether a string contains an alphabetic character, then simply do:

```
/[a-z]/i.test(str)
```

If the string should be composed of only alphanumeric characters with at least one alphabetic character:

```
/^(?=.*[a-z])[a-z\d]+$/i.test(str)
```

or

```
/[a-z]/i.test(str) && /^[a-z\d]+$/i.test(str)
```

Otherwise, `[a-zA-Z0-9.'\-_\s]{1,20}` looks good to me actually, but you have to anchor it to the beginning and end of the string:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9.'\-_\s]{1,20}$/.test(str)
```

If you want to enforce an alphabetic character, you have to include the lookahead or make an extra test, just like in the previous example.

Answer (score 0):

I went to the Angular Docs and found this. Maybe it is very simple but does what I need

```
<input name="firstName" ngModel pattern="[a-zA-Z ]*">
```

https://angular.io/api/forms/PatternValidator#adding-a-pattern-validator